# Validate empty field for tinymceeditor

Tags: javascript, validation

Im trying to apply empty filed validation for tinymceeditor as:

```
<li>
  <label for="contents"><?php echo $this->__('Preparation Steps: ');?></label>
  <textarea class="description isfield_required8 tinymceeditor mcontent validate-alphanum " name="contents"><?php echo @$recipe?@$recipe->getContents():''; ?></textarea>
</li>

<script type="text/javascript">
Validation.add('isfield_required8', '<?php echo $hlp->__('Please fill the recipe Prpe step'); ?>', function(v) {
    return !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v);
});
```

But it is not showing any warning for empty filed.
Is the code right?